# Proving an implication in probabilty

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Being $(\Omega,F,P)$ a probability space and {$A_i$} an independent set sequence with $A_i \in F$, $i=1,2,... $

How can I prove that if  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i) =\infty$, then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} P\bigl(\cap_{i=1}^n \cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\bigl)=1$$

Comment: Do you want maybe $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\bigcup_{k=i}^\infty A_k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [second Borel Cantelli Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result). You can find the proof in most introductory probability textbooks or on Wikipedia.